# passing variable to flash

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am trying to pass variable to below flash value '2163137' which is location_id. I want to pass dynamic variable using javascript.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://swf.yowindow.com/yowidget3.swf" width="220" height="150">
        <param name="movie" value="http://swf.yowindow.com/yowidget3.swf"/>
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/>
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
        <param name="flashvars" 
        value="location_id=gn:2163137&amp;location_name=Hornsby&amp;time_format=24&amp;unit_system=metric&amp;background=#FFFFFF&amp;copyright_bar=false"
    />
```

I tried various thing but simply i am not getting any idea how i should achieve it. Any idea?

Comment: And how are you using them in Flash itself?

Comment: I see 2 possible issues in your object, 1) the ":" may need to be urlencoded (i.e., value="location_id=gn%3A2163137) and 2) you might need to change "flashvars" to the case-sensitive "FlashVars".  Would using SWFObject would make this easier?  See https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/.

Answer (score 0):

In Flash `LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.location_id` will return the value `gn:2163137`.  See [this description from Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html).